# Disable Pinch Zoom on iOS 10+ Safari - React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

according to [disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari) there is a need to override this in the following way (in JS):

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
  if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
}, false);
```

However in TypeScript this gives:

> [ts] Property 'scale' does not exist on type 'TouchEvent'. [2339]

I have tried to use the solutions at [Does TypeScript support TouchEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869055/does-typescript-support-touchevent) - but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to incorporate a touchevent into TypeScript?

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue? Have you found any?

Comment: Unfortunately not